# How do I save a logo as a bitmap?

Tags: bitmap

I need to save a logo as a bitmap, 256 colors or less and no larger than 64K. I have no idea what these requirements mean.

Comment: Please update your question to include what you've tried (such as what programs you've used or have access to). A Google search will find many programs capable of doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Most designers would use a program like Adobe Photoshop. Us open source people would probably use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), which is a free image editing program. For Windows, there's also Paint.net, which is also free and easy to use, but lighter on the features.

You can actually do what you want with Microsoft Paint, which you already have (if you are using Windows).

1. Open the image with Paint
2. On the **File** menu, click **Save As > BMP picture**
3. In the **Save as type** box, change the type to *256 Color Bitmap*.

You'll need to double check the size of your BMP file. If it is more than 256 colors, you can open it in Paint again and save it again as a PNG file, which will have a smaller size (since the BMP was saved limited to 256 colors, the PNG should only have those same colors)

If you want to edit image files more frequently, install Gimp or another image editing program.

Answer (score 1):

First, 256 color means the spectrum of colors for web. So, just be sure to save whatever file for web, at least this will be the best way. 
64k is the file size limit. Be sure to save whatever file size to that limit. You can check this by looking at the file size afterwards wherever you saved it. K = kilobyte.
As for the tile type, it is a bitmap, so...
Create your logo, convert colors to indexed web/save for web, then select file type as bitmap (btmp). You may run in to serious file size problems, so keep it in mind that your logo will have to be very small for this.
Honestly, this almost seems like a joke.

Comment: I kind of felt that way too. Basically she is using it for their customer database software which leads me to believe it'll be itty bitty and never printed.

Comment: When it come to a logo being itty-bitty, might just with a b/w and keep it simple. I mean, at that size, we are talking smaller than a shilling or penny.